# Unable to clone enyo2-components on windows from github

Tags: git, github, git-bash, enyo

I am newbie to both git & enyo framework.I installed git-bash on my windows-7 and trying to clonse enjyo2-components repo to my local machine.
I forked it & copied url `https://github.com/kshraddha1290/enyo-2-components.git`.When I try to clone it using command

`$ git clone https://github.com/kshraddha1290/enyo-2-components.git` ,nothing happnes.If I try to clone it in specific directory i.e.

`$ git clone https://github.com/kshraddha1290/enyo-2-components.git xml/`,the directory `xml` gets deleted.

Please tell what m I missing?

**EDIT**

Following is all output I get

`$ git clone https://github.com/kshraddha1290/enyo-2-components.git`

`Cloning into 'enyo-2-components'...`

`project@project-PC MINGW32 ~
$`

Comment: Does it print any error messages?

Comment: no error messages if I clone it in current directory,however if I give path then it prints

`Deletion of directory '.' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)`

Comment: Do you see this message when you `clone` the repo?

Comment: Yes before throwing this message it says

`Cloning into '.'...`

Comment: It might be a good idea to attach all the output that you have

Comment: Check my edited question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87484/discussion-between-newhorizens-and-zaratustra).

Comment: Just as a note, this repo has submodules.  You may want to add the `--recursive` flag to the clone command when you get it working.